# React native error cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIBlock, any ideas?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Am getting below build error when I hit run-android
cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIBlock

It came after this warning.
Configure project :react-native-gesture-handler
WARNING: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Any ideas?